# Suggested edits pending approval leads to nowhere.

Tags: bug, status-completed

Today I found the oragne button.
[image: suggested edits]

Unfortunately, when I click on it, I get sent to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits
which gives me Page Not Found error. 
What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this should be fixed now.

Comment: Nope, it's not fixed now.  OK, so the orange button isn't present (because we have no suggested edits), but it should say "No edits pending" instead of "Page Not Found".

Comment: @reemrevnivek  What are suggested edits? I thought that it was something to be implemented in the future and that the button is there by accident, so I accepted the answer.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - They're a new feature: Users without enough rep to make an edit can propose one, and it goes into a queue (which was the link you discovered) where users with more rep can approve or deny the edit.  It's new, so the bugs are understandable, but you can read more about it on [this meta.stackoverflow answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284) (they have a whole [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) about it).